# How to write a Chef recipe to copy a file if that source file exists? only_if guard not working

Tags: ruby, tomcat, deployment, chef-infra

I'm currently working on a simple script to handle properties files during a Chef deployment. I'm executing the following code with `chef-apply script.rb`

```
class_path = '/var/lib/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes'
file '/home/corp/working/corp.properties' do
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode 0644
  p File.exist?("#{class_path}")
  content File.open("#{class_path}/corp.properties").read
  action :create_if_missing
  only_if { File.exist?("#{class_path}/corp.properties") }
end
```

But it runs with the error

```
false
[2017-12-20T11:37:40-05:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /home/corp/.chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2017-12-20T11:37:40-05:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /home/corp/.chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2017-12-20T11:37:40-05:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2017-12-20T11:37:40-05:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2017-12-20T11:37:40-05:00] FATAL: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/corp.properties
[2017-12-20T11:37:40-05:00] FATAL: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/corp.properties
```

As you can see, even though the `File.exist?` call is returning false, the File.open is being executed regardless of the guard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any code in the resource block defaults to being run at compile time. Guards run at converge time. You can fix this by making it `content lazy { File.open("#{class_path}/corp.properties").read }` to force the file read to happen at converge time instead. See https://coderanger.net/two-pass/ for more info.